# Selenium XPath Dynamic Variable with Loops VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to loop a variable value in xpath, this is my wrong try:

> `cd.FindElementByXPath("(//textarea[contains(@class,'form-control ')])[' + b + ']").SendKeys Sheets2.Cells(1, "d")`

I want "b" letter as variable...
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the single quotes i.e. `'...'` with double quotes i.e. `"..."` around the variable **`b`** as follows:

```
cd.FindElementByXPath("(//textarea[contains(@class,'form-control ')])[" & b & "]").SendKeys Sheets2.Cells(1, "d")
```

or

```
cd.FindElementsByXPath("(//textarea[contains(@class,'form-control ')])[" & b & "]").SendKeys Sheets2.Cells(1, "d")
```

Comment: I'm sorry when run the code as this type mismatch error appears.

Comment: Hmmm, `b` being an index you need `FindElements*` instead of `FindElement*`. Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, type mismatch error again... I can't find the solution... b has to be integer and there are 144 values for b.

Comment: No, not worked... Syntax Error appeared

Comment: Synax Error again

Comment: not worked these two codes

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _not worked_? _`type mismatch error`_ or _`Synax Error`_?

Comment: type mismatch error

Comment: type mismatch error again

Comment: by the way when I wrote any numbers for b code is running succesfully...

Comment: I found the solution vba not use +, uses &....  so the code has to be as: I'm trying to loop a variable value in xpath, this is my wrong try:

cd.FindElementByXPath("(//textarea[contains(@class,'form-control ')])[" & b & "]").SendKeys Sheets2.Cells(1, "d")

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Okay :) I'm not a VB guy, I only know little Selenium ;) Updated the answer accordingly.